# Regular expression help to get the opposite in a gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have below regular expression that check whether we do not have `--deploy` in a commit message

```
deploy_review:
  <<: *deploy_review_base
  except:
    refs:
      - tags
      - master
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "review" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^.*--deploy/
```

Now I want to check the opposite of this, that is I want to check where this string `--deploy` is present in a commit message. Opposite of above expression. is there a way to achieve this ?

Appreciate any help on this

Thanks,

Comment: `!~` is already checking whether you don't have that pattern while  `=~` is to check whether you have that pattern. . not sure about your question here.

Answer (score 3):

To invert the matching logic, just use `=~` instead of `!~`.

Though your current logic (using `!~`) checks that the regex pattern does *not* match. `=~` is used to check if the regex pattern *does* match. You should double check your regex pattern works as expected.

Comment: actually my regex pattern is working as expected, whenever I add `--deploy` to a commit message it recognizes that

Comment: but your answer also correct, I'm using this regex inside `except` clause so that it make sense the way it behaves. I'll update the question to reflect the same so there won't be any confusions for future readers